# SOQL: Avoid count with NULL results return 0 (zero) instead

Tags: mysql, sql, salesforce, soql

I have a problem, I have written a query and I need to return the count of opportunities in the given order: Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4. The problem is that if the count is NULL for example for Name2, then the query returns Name1_count, Name3_count, Name4_count.

I need to make sure that I always get the values in the right order and if the value is null i need to get back 0. But its not working :(

I tried:

```
Select Owner.Name
      ,IF(ISBLANK(count(id))
      ,0
      ,count(id)) 

  from Opportunity 

  where CloseDate = Today 
    and Approved__c = true 
    and (Owner.Name = 'Name1' 
         or Owner.Name = 'Name2' 
         or Owner.Name = 'Name3' 
         or Owner.Name = 'Name4') 

  group by Owner.Name
```

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Hey unfortunaltely i get an empty response every morning (when no opportunities have been closed) and if an employee is e.g. on vacation (e.g. name2) the order result is wrong because name2 will not occur in the result.

Comment: i would want to get
name1: 0
name2: 0
name3: 0
name4: 0

so instead of not showing any results for null results it should list the result with 0

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses a table alias called `owner` which is not defined.  Presumably, this is supposed to refer to `Opportunity`, although that is just a guess.  Also, to get a `0` when you have a `NULL`, the typical function is `coalesce()`.  And I replaced the complicated set of `or`s with `in`:

```
Select o.Name, coalesce(count(id), 0) 
from Opportunity o
where CloseDate = Today and Approved__c = true and
      o.Name in ('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4')
group by o.Name ;
```

Finally, to get all four names in the output, you need to use `left outer join`:

```
Select names.Name, count(o.id) as cnt
from (select 'Name1' as name union all select 'Name2' union all
      select 'Name3' union all select 'Name4'
     ) names left outer join
     Opportunity o
     on names.name = o.name
where CloseDate = Today and Approved__c = true
group by names.Name ;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer! Unfortunaltly i cant get it work at the moment. Question for my understanding: Do i need a coalesce() in the 2nd query as well to make sure that i get a 0 result if null?

Comment: @user3472527 . . . No.  In this context, `count(<column>)` will return `0` when there are no rows that match in the second table.

Comment: hmm i get a syntax error.. i am pretty new to SOQL (NOT SQL) and imho SOQL does not support OUTER JOIN or even UNION ALL statements?

Comment: MySQL definitely does.  I don't know about SOQL.  Does it support subqueries?

Comment: yes i understand that in mysql this would work but here we would have multiple options such as isnull() etc. all this is not existing in SOQL... thanks anyway for your help